# Angular 4 - event propagation in routed app between header component and routed component

Tags: angular, events, angular-routing, event-propagation

I have this construction of a main component:

```
<section id="page-container" class="app-page-container">
  <my-app-header></my-app-header>

  <div class="app-content-wrapper">
    <div class="app-content">
      <div class="full-height">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      </div>
    </div>

    <my-app-footer></my-app-footer>
  </div>
</section>
```

And I have to propagate an event (language change is what this is about), from `AppHeaderComponent` (`my-app-header` in the template) to any component that is routed to. (loaded inside `router-outlet`). How can I do this? Thanks for the suggestion guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a **[`Subject`](https://blog.angularindepth.com/rxjs-understanding-subjects-5c585188c3e1)** of type string using a shared service,

```
selectedLanguage: Subject<string>;
```

In your component,

```
setLanguage(selectedValue: any): void {
        this.selectedLanguage = selectedValue;
        this.appService.selectedLanguage.next(this.selectedLanguage);
}
```

and wherever you need to access

```
this.appService.selectedLanguage.asObservable().subscribe((value: any) => {
    this.selectedLanguage = value;
});
```

Comment: Ok, but wht is appService? I have to import it, probably? I have another service, maybe I can use that one, but it is used for REST API.

Comment: @VladimirDespotovic i would recommend you to create new service to handle all these kind of scenarios. like a commonsharedservice. yes you need to import it inside module.ts

Comment: Ok, does it extend an existing Angular class? The service that I need.

Comment: Not necessary export class AppSharedService {

Comment: What do I need inside of it? A static method or something similar?

Comment: yes just a member  selectedLanguage: Subject<string>;

Comment: Where will this code go:         this.selectedLanguage = selectedValue;
        this.appService.selectedLanguage.next(this.selectedLanguage);
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165082/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-vladimir-despotovic).

Comment: And also, do I have to have the method next()?

Answer (score 1):

You must have a service and share that between your components. In your service you will have an observable and register to that every where you want, and also some functions to change your observable state. I prefer to use a `BehaviorSubject`.

Your service should be something like this:

```
export class SomeService {

    showNavigation = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

    constructor() {
    }

    showBackButton() {
        this.showNavigation.next(true);
    }

    hideBackButton() {
        this.showNavigation.next(false);
    }
}
```

And use it in your headerComponent like this:

```
//inject the service in your constructor
ngOnInit() {
        this.SomeService.showNavigation.subscribe((isShown: boolean) => {
            this.shownavigation = isShown;
        });
    }
```

And then you can change the state everywhere you want in your components, again you must inject the service to your component constructor.

```
constructor(private someService: SomeService) {

    this.someService.showBackButton();
}
```

And you will see the event is being propagate by calling the method.

Comment: Hi! Can you explain to me these two lines:
1. this.showNavigation.next(false);
and
2. showNavigation = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

Comment: From where do I find the BehaviorSubject class to import it?

Comment: Can you tell me what is the next() method for? I see you are always using exactly this method...

Comment: Using next() method you can send values to the observable. for more info on behaviourSubject refer [here](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/behaviorsubject.md)

Comment: In this line `showNavigation = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);` we create a class level variable of type BehaviorSubject, with `boolean` data type, which always need an initial value, in this case `false`. BehaviorSubject is a observable and observer in the meantime.

Comment: import {BehaviorSubject} from "rxjs/BehaviorSubject";